# Aluminum winding in inverters

Tags: power-supply, inverter, efficiency

I am planning to buy inverter. 
I finalized one model; however, I was told that it uses aluminum windings whereas the other model has copper windings. They recomended I should buy the one with copper windings because it will have more **longetivity** and **efficiency**.
Is this true? What about heating?

I found this link on the web but it does not say anything about aluminum, just copper and silver winding comparison.
http://upsinverterinfo.com/is-microtek-silver-winding-inverter-better-than-luminous-copper-winding.html

Answer (score 2):

The primary driver here is probably cost. Aluminium is cheaper then copper.

For high-current windings, you need a lot of copper/aluminium. I'd imagine that by switching to aluminium, the manufacturers can save money in the transformer production expenses.

Regarding "longevity" and "efficiency":

- [Aluminium can be difficult to connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_wire) to, if connectors designed specifically for aluminium are not used.
- Copper is a better conductor then aluminium, though this can be compensated for by simply using more and thicker aluminium. However, this will likely require the aluminium-wiring transformer to be physically larger.
- This could lead to more leakage flux, rendering the transformer less efficient.

---

Realistically, the major factors in what makes a quality transformer are independent from the transformer winding material all together. You can have crappy copper transformers, or great aluminium transformers.

Chose based on actual quality, warranty, etc....

Comment: +1 AL is cheaper generally as noted. If a manufacturer uses AL they are aiming at cost cutting but have had to take care with core volume and winding space. This probably means they know what they are doing or that they are cutting corners. If all else indicates that it is quality product it means they are probably competent and that longevity should be OK.

Comment: Please tell me about heating also.Does one generates more heat than other during operation of inverter?

Comment: @Arun - Heating is orthogonal to the material. If you underspec a copper winding, it will overheat. If you overspec aluminium windings, it will not even get warm. "Heating" is a function of a separate design parameter (conductor equivalent gauge). It is independent of the actual material.